# Missing Update Software preference on Macbook Pro Early 2015

Tags: macbook-pro, software-update

My Macbook Pro has no 'Software Update' setting icon. It's not listed. If I run `sudo softwareupdate --install --all` it comes back with `No updates are available`. Looking through Activity Monitor shows no `softwareupdated`.

The laptop also behaves weirdly in that screen display refreshes are super slow sometimes. Almost every website has a security warning (despite clearing my cache or changing browsers). The newest version of Chrome I can download is V87.0.4280.88. There are other little things but the gist is it seems off. So I am trying to update, but can't. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Thanks @davidAnderson. I tied this but it didn't work. App Store keeps prompting for 'Validation Required' which takes me to a page to update my apple id information which then takes me back to the Monterey page in App Store. So it's an endless loop. There is something going on with this pc.

Answer (score -1):

Never figured out what was going on but after chatting and then speaking to Apple tech support the solution was to boot with, I think, <kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> pressed then use the resulting boot menu to install macOS Monterey.

In the process, several things were going wrong/were unusual. This may be because this laptop was used by a person that tweaked many accessibility settings due to their physical disabilities.

Comment: *"what was going on"* Yosemite was far too old to have the Update control panel. It was also too old to access the App Store properly. In jumping straight to Monterey, you missed out on an important firmware update - which it must have fetched at some point in your procedure.